# Problems with return of text based on Json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I want to create a text on screen based on my JSON data with the help of d3.js.
I want to the "name" attribute of my JSON to be appear on screen, but something is not right in my short code. Can someone of you guys help?

Thanks!

Here is the JSON data called

> testjson.json
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "peter",
>   "id": "13",
> }
> ```

And here is the code:

```
  var svg = d3.select("body")
          .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width)    
          .attr("height", height); 


  d3.json("testjson.json", function() { 
      var text = svg.append("text")
      .data("testjson.json")
    .attr("dx", 30)
    .attr("dy", 111)
    .text(function(d) { return d.name})
    )};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d3.json("testjson.json", function(json) { 
    var text = svg.append("text")
            .datum(json)
            .attr("dx", 30)
            .attr("dy", 111)
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
});
```

Comment: Hello Noelia, are you sure about this? I tried and it does not work.

Comment: @Suppe

I tried this on the chrome console:

`d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/heyimnowi/d41f794458d8d89a121c81a7485a248f/raw/e61a1fcdf0d3a16f22ade3dd5f5d953c8bd00527/.csscomb.json", function(json) { 

d3.select('body').append("text")
       .datum(json)
     .attr("dx", 10)
     .attr("dy", 20)
     .text(function(d) { return d; });

});`

Comment: Sorry about the format haha I don't know how to beautified it

Comment: Are you sure that are you copying my example properly? Which error are you getting? It appends an empty text to the body? Or it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @NoeliaBelenLopez OP is probably using still `data()`. Unlike `datum()`, `data()` does not accept an object, only **arrays**. If that is the case, tell OP to use `data([json])`, or just use `datum()` as you correctly suggested.